# .htaccess disable password protection if certain get parameter is set to certain value

Tags: .htaccess, authentication, get, password-protection

We try to disable our password protection for internal use. Therefore we'd like to be able to add a parameter to the url which does this. We know that everybody who knows this parameter will have access to the directory. Now what we've tried so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Do the regex check against the URI here, if match, set the "require_auth" var
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$ 
RewriteRule (.*auth=mysecurehash.*) $1 [E=require_auth:false] 

#Auth stuff
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /.htpasswd
AuthName "Enter Username and Password"

# Setup a deny/allow
Order Deny,Allow
# Deny from everyone
Deny from all
# except if either of these are satisfied
Satisfy any
# 1. a valid authenticated user
Require valid-user
# or 2. the "require_auth" var is NOT set
Allow from env=!require_auth
```

This should disable auth for `anydir/anfile.any?auth=mysecurehash`
but unfortunately it doesn't.

Actually everybody does have acces now - without password.

What are we missing?

Comment: Have you tried to change order to "allow, deny"?

Comment: If I change, everybody is asked for a password, no matter if `require_auth` is set or not

Comment: We're still unable to find a solution for this problem. I would really appreciate another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your rule with the following

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} auth=mysecurehash [NC] 
 RewriteRule ^ - [E=require_auth:false]
```

FYI , query strings are not part of match in RewriteRule directive, we need to use a RewriteCond to match againgst urls with querystrings.

Try the following :

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} auth=mysecurehash [NC] 
 RewriteRule ^ - [E=require_auth:false] 
#Auth stuff
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /.htpasswd
AuthName "Enter Username and Password"

#Here is where we allow/deny
Order Deny,Allow
Satisfy any
Deny from all
Require valid-user
Allow from env=require_auth
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. Unfortunately the authentication still doesn't work. All users do now have access to it. No matter if the `?auth=mysecurehash` is added or not.

Comment: Thank you for you effort. Unfortunately this caused the htaccess to always ask for a password (even with `?auth=mysecurehash`)

Comment: Do you have any other idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

With 2.4 you can do it with easy by `<If>` directive.

For 2.2 you can try to redirect all requests without/without param to specific virtual URL and than use

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/virturl.html require_auth=false
```

and then

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Satisfy any
Require valid-user
Allow from env=!require_auth
```

something like that